# Send HTTP Requests (MEAN stack)

Tags: api, rest, client-side

I am working with MEAN stack (MongoDB , ExpressJS, AngularJS and NodeJS). I know how are GET,POST,DELETE and PUT handled in the server side but problem comes from the client side. For example - given a button "Register" I want to send a POST req but I don't know how. I only need explanation - not any code or something else. Help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular provides `$http` module which you can use in your client code to make GET, POST, PUT and DELETE operation.

On your html, you should have a listener(by using `ng-click` if you are using angular) for `"Register"` Button. In your function definition you can use `$http.post(<url>, <data>)` to make a request.

Here is the relevant video tutorial of probably what you are trying to acheive https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-http